# Axes displaying correctly with scale, but graph bars not being drawn correctly

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js

I'm trying to display a dataset as a graph, but while the x and y axes are displaying correctly with respect to the x and y scales that I've set, the graph bars are not being drawn on the SVG canvas appropriately.

This is the graph that is displayed:[image]

This is what I have for the dataset and svg components as written in CoffeeScript:

```
dataset = [[1992, 1], [1994, 3], [1995, 3], [1996, 1], [1997, 3], [1998, 6], [1999, 11], [2000, 36], [2001, 37], 
        [2002, 46], [2003, 171], [2004, 442], [2005, 514], [2006, 753], [2007, 756],
        [2008, 660], [2009, 829], [2010, 903], [2011, 4425], [2012, 1635], [2013, 8]]

w = 800
h = 500
padding = 40

xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([d3.min(dataset, (d)-> d[0]) - 1, d3.max(dataset, (d)-> d[0]) + 1])
        .range([padding, w - padding * 2])

yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, (d)-> d[1])])
        .range([h - padding, padding])

xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .tickFormat(d3.format("0"))

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left')

svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)

svg.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', (d)-> xScale(d[0]))
    .attr('y', (d)-> yScale(d[0]))
    .attr('width', (d, i)-> w / dataset.length * i)
    .attr('height', (d)-> d * 4)

svg.selectAll('text')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', (d)-> xScale(d[0]))
    .attr('y', (d)-> yScale(d[1]))

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (h - padding) + ')')
    .call(xAxis)

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + padding + ',0)')
    .call(yAxis)
```

Comment: Did you check the console? There are errors:  `Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN"`.  Also, your other problem is here:  `.attr('height', (d)-> d * 4)`.  `d` is an object so you'll need to use `d[1]` instead (since it's the y value).

Comment: There are currently no console errors. I changed the width and height attributes to be (d)-> xScale(d[0]) and (d)-> yScale(d[1]) respectively and got this: http://imgur.com/3Hf8Ecu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code:

```
.attr('width', (d, i)-> w / dataset.length * i)
.attr('height', (d)-> d * 4)
```

Both have problems.

For width, you shouldn't multiply by `i`, or even have to depend on data. Need something more like:

```
.attr('width', widthPerYear) // don't need a function here
```

`widthPerYear` is something you need to decide on. Technically, it can be `w/dataset.length`, but that assumes dataset is the same length as the entire range.

For height, you need

```
.attr('y', (d)-> h - yScale(d[1]))
```